# Issue in deployment of react app in netlify

Tags: javascript, reactjs, npm, create-react-app, netlify

- I am trying to deploy react application in netlify as referred from the medium link: https://link.medium.com/nw9ZCh0lrV
- so I used express server to define build scripts and setting application in production mode
- Build scripts are creating in local machine and uploaded in netlify site
- It shows message as successful deployment
- on clicking on URL link, it shows status to GET request for build scripts as 404
- netlify URL link: https://nostalgic-euclid-4f95ab.netlify.com
- can you guys help me where I have done mistake with your suggestion
- attached application screenshots below
  -providing code snippets below:

server.js

```
const express = require('express');
const favicon = require('express-favicon');
const app = express();

app.use(favicon(__dirname + '/build/favicon.ico'));
app.use(express.static(__dirname));
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname,'build')));
app.get('/*', function (req, res) {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'build', 'index.html'));
});
```

packagae.json

```
"scripts" : {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  }
```

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A common mistake in a `create react app` is to add a `homepage` in the `package.json` file that does not match your site location. Once you do a production build, the assets are prepended with the value of any path after the domain.

`https://nostalgic-euclid-4f95ab.netlify.com/codehangar/react-interview/static/js/main.7ab6795d.chunk.js`

From the look of the path of the broken (404) asset, your homepage value looks something like:

```
  "homepage": "https://example.com/codehangar/react-interview",
```

If you are going to include a homepage value, make sure it is the same as your site URL.

In your case the value should be:

```
  "homepage": " https://nostalgic-euclid-4f95ab.netlify.com",
```

***Note:**** Typically, leave this setting out of the file until you are live and have your domain set.

Also:

- No need to store the build folder in your repository (.gitignore). The build command will replace it on each deploy.
- You will not need the `server.js` file you supplied.

Comment: @talves...thanks a lot for your reply...its working...your explanation is really good...

Comment: @talves...I am also trying to deploy java spring boot app in AWS, but facing issue in deployment process which I have posted in stack overflow and its link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55346085/deployment-issue-of-java-spring-boot-app-on-aws .... If possible, can you kindly look into it and provide your suggestions for it

Comment: confirmed. package.json "homepage" was the culprit. deleted it all together

Answer (score 0):

Try using manual uploading the build file
on `netlify drop`

Answer (score 0):

Place _redirects file in public directory and in package.json file try changing homepage value as this worked for me

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).