# HTTP GET response 304 status error after deploying react app on netlify

Tags: javascript, reactjs, npm, netlify

- I deployed react application in netlify
- so I used npm run build command for building local scripts and manually deployed application in netlify for production mode
- Build scripts are creating in local machine and uploaded in netlify site
- It shows message as successful deployment
- on clicking on URL link, previously shows status to GET request for build scripts as 404
- After including redirects file in build folder, it changed for status to GET request for build scripts as 304 and showing error as

  > syntax error: uncaught error : unexpected token <
- For debugging, I commented files and run the code to find out the error
- But, unable to find the root error
- can you guys help me where I have done mistake with your suggestion
- netlify URL link:  https://lucid-shaw-bb2b3f.netlify.com
- The application code is available in github and its link: https://github.com/aarivalagan/react-one
- attached application screenshots below
- providing code snippet below:

_redirects

```
/*     /index.html   200!
```

packagae.json

```
"scripts" : {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  }
```

[image]

Comment: You now have 2 questions going about one site caused by the same issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are going to put a `_redirects` into your `create react app`, it should go into the `public` folder. The build folder should not be in your repository for continuous build solutions like Netlify.

The `_redirects` you suggest here are typically used for when you use single page apps with a router like react router and want a path to always go to `index.html`when it does not exist. You would not want it to resolve asset value paths.

> This redirect rule will serve the index.html instead of giving a 404 no matter what URL the browser requests.

`_redirects`

```
/*    /index.html   200
```

What is happening is you are forcing the index.html page to serve up even if there is not a valid path, which is happening with your assets.

- Fix the [original issue](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55436186/2597114)
- Move the `_redirects` to `public` folder
- remove the `!` from the end of the redirects, so if a path is found it serves it correctly and not always forcing it to `index.html`

Comment: thanks a lot for your reply...its working...your explanation is really good